# lldb printf in xcode 12

Tags: xcode, expression, lldb

XCode 12.4 , lldb debug on one IOS app

using command 'expression'

```
(int) printf("hello world\n");
```

no output ,but

```
(void) NSLog(@"hello world\n");
```

it did work , why ? can I change to C/C++ mode ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSKr.png)

also, I find that

`(void) NSLog(@"number = %i", 123);`

result is "number = 307823584".

i don't know what it means. it seem that only objc object is allowed ?

```
SString* temp = @"yuv"; 
(void) NSLog(@"str = %@", temp);
```

output is "str = yuv" (corret)
but

```
(void) NSLog(@"str = %s", "123456");
```

output is "str = »¡#" (error)

Comment: Did you run the iOS app in the debugger, or did you attach to the app?  NSLog and printf go to different places.  NSLog goes to the os_log channel, and then there's some magic that routes this back to the debugger console.  printf goes wherever stdout goes.  If you run under the debugger, stdout should go back to Xcode, but finger-launched apps on iOS route stdout to /dev/null, and Xcode doesn't have a good way to change that.

Comment: I don't see the bugs you mention with NSLog.  %i should bring numbers correctly, and the string should also work, even string constants invented in the expression parser.  If you can reproduce these reliably please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com with instructions on how to repro (preferably with an example project so we're all on the same page).  Thanks!